# How to prevent unchanged StatelessWidget rebuild inside Stateful parent?

Tags: flutter

I have actually been writing Flutter code for many years now, apparently under a false assumption: I always believed that a widget's `build()` function was only called if a) its parameters changed or b) its constraints changed. But in the process of testing a performance issue in an app, I discovered that this actually isn't true, and now I feel kind of stupid.

For example (runs in dartpad):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Content(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Content extends StatefulWidget {
  const Content({super.key});

  @override
  State<Content> createState() => _ContentState();
}

class _ContentState extends State<Content> {
  int countFoo = 0;
  int countBar = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Counter(id: 'foo', count: countFoo),
        Counter(id: 'bar', count: countBar),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() => countFoo++),
          child: const Text('Foo++'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() => countBar++),
          child: const Text('Bar++'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final int count;

  const Counter({
    super.key,
    required this.id,
    required this.count,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Build counter $id: $count');
    return Text('Count ($id): $count');
  }
}
```

I would have thought that in this case, clicking the Foo++ button would change the `countFoo` parameter, and setState would cause the `Content`'s `build` function to run, which would go through the widgets and mark the Foo `Counter` to rebuild, since the parameter changed, but not the Bar `Counter`, since it's the same.

What actually happens is both `Counter` widgets have their `build` function called each time *either* of the buttons is pressed, which is news to me. I have also tried passing a `Key` to each `Counter`, and making them stateful (with the count still coming in as a parameter).

So my question is: how does one build something like this, such that when a parent widget's state changes, it doesn't necessarily cause the rebuild of every child, but only the ones that need rebuilding?

In this case obviously `Counter` could be made into a stateful widget, but what if the count *needs* to come from above? There are lots of reasons this could be, and this is just a minimal example of what I mean.

Anyway thanks in advance and please try not to make me feel any more stupid than I already do :)

Comment: I can think of using stateless widget on parent and hanle the stateChange on counter or using ValuNotifier

Answer (score 0):

See commonly, making the `Widget` `Stateless` and using it as const solves the issue, As using it as `const` tells Flutter that these widgets are immutable and can be reused without rebuilding. But here as you're passing the values of `countFoo` and `counterBar` it's not possible.

So there's several solutions to this, you can use `Bloc`, `Cubit` or other state management tool, or `ValueNotifier` or a `Stream` to manage the state .

here i'm taking example of `ValueNotifier`:

```
class Content extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Content> createState() => _ContentState();
}

class _ContentState extends State<Content> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> countFoo = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  final ValueNotifier<int> countBar = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Counter(id: 'foo', countNotifier: countFoo),
        Counter(id: 'bar', countNotifier: countBar),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => countFoo.value++,
          child: const Text('Foo++'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => countBar.value++,
          child: const Text('Bar++'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    countFoo.dispose();
    countBar.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final ValueNotifier<int> countNotifier;

  const Counter({
    required this.id,
    required this.countNotifier,
  });

  @override
  State<Counter> createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.countNotifier.addListener(_update);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Build counter ${widget.id}: ${widget.countNotifier.value}');
    return Text('Count (${widget.id}): ${widget.countNotifier.value}');
  }

  void _update() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.countNotifier.removeListener(_update);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

and a small explanation:

- Each `Counter` widget receiving a `ValueNotifier<int>`.
- The `Counter` widget adds a listener to the `countNotifier` in its `initState`, so it will only rebuild when its associated count changes.
- When the button is pressed, it increments the corresponding `countNotifier`, which triggers the listener in the associated `Counter`, causing it to rebuild.